# Vue Webpack load code splitting file and show loader

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I am currently using code splitting with Vue and Vue-Webpack.

In my router/index.html I do something like this:

```
const Dashboard = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ '@/components/Dashboard.vue');
```

This works great, and the component is being loaded but no loading feedback is showing to the user. Is there any code I can inject between the user requesting a component to be loaded and when it is actually done?

Cheers,
Erwin

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic imports return a promise so you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
Dashboard.then(() => {
    // Remove your spinner or loading animation.
})
```

Before the import you would always show your spinner and in your `then` resolve, you would remove it.

Haven't worked that much with dynamic import so this might not work.